# scheduled task process.closemainwindow

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, task, scheduler

Please let me know if i'm coming at this from a completely wrong angle. I have a console application which I'm trying to run as a scheduled task, what it does is identifies a process being start by it's processID, it will close the process (not kill it as this will kill all instances of said process and not one that has been clearly identified) and display a message (not required but good to notify the user), the issue i'm having is that process.kill() works fine, does what i need to plus that extra bit more which i don't want it to, however the method which i require which is process.closemainwindow() fails to work, any ideas?

Below is part of my code:

```
DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

            var query = from d in dc.Tables
                        where d.ApplicationName == Application.ProcessName
                        select d;

            foreach (var app in query)
            {
                if (app.LicenseTotal < 1)
                {
                    foreach (Process p in processname)
                    {
                        if (Application.LicensesInUse < 1)
                        {
                            p.CloseMainWindow();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should really avoid trying to roll your own licencing.  It's a very hard problem, and there are lots of existing products out there that will almost certainly do way more than you'll be able to manage on your own.

Comment: fair enough but this one issue is what's blocking me from completion

Comment: And yet your licencing software is subverted by as simple of a tactic as renaming the executable file.  And of course if a user is an admin on their own machine (which they probably are) they can kill your scheduled task easily enough.

Comment: This will be done on a restricted system so permissions and .exe renaming is nothing to worry about